# Am I allowed to use Wikipedia content?

Tags: licensing, wikipedia

I'm always confused when reading licenses ....

I want to implement (to be honest implementation is already done) a commercial iPad app which makes use of content from wikipedia. Am I allowed to

- Embed hardcoded links that point to wikipedia articles and display those in an in app browser?
- Implement an aggresive caching that mirrors part of wikipedia to make content available offline?
- manually download wikipedia articles during dev time and bundle the content within my app?

Comment: "I'm always confused when reading licenses"..well you aren't the only one..:(

Comment: I thought so, but thanks - it's always good to know, that I'm not alone.

Comment: I guess it is correct to close this one, but I would like to know the answer of this one as well..Will any other stackexchange site takes a question like this? programmers,eh?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wikipedia's content is licensed under Creative Commons, the one that allows commercial usage. Open [Main page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) and scroll to the very bottom of it. See that small text:

> Text is available under the Creative
>   Commons Attribution-ShareAlike
>   License; additional terms may apply.
>   See Terms of Use for details.

You should have checked that investing time implementing something.

[Here is the license itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License) (slightly shortened by me, not original text):

You are free:

- to Share—to copy, distribute and transmit the work, and
- to Remix—to adapt the work

Under the following conditions:

- Attribution
- Share Alike

Comment: But doesn't "Share-Alike" mean, that I'm not allowed to distribute my app commercially via app store (only)?

Comment: @Kai ShareAlike means: "If you alter, transform, or build upon this work, you may distribute the resulting work only under the same, similar or a compatible license." You are not building upon it actually, you just deliver content, your application is not derivative. It means if you write your own article build upon wikipedia (not citation) you must share alike. Don't worry.

Answer (score 8):

The [Wikipedia license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License) is actually one of the easier to read, although it needs to be read in conjunction with the [Terms of Use](http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use) (which defines the Attribution conditions among others).

In short, you can share and alter the content as long as you attribute it correctly (typically by hyperlinking back to Wikipedia), and you use the same license for any alterations you make.

Comment: The Terms of Use are more to govern a user's interaction with Wikipedia sites (posting false statements, harassment, paid contributions etc.). If your app let people make corrections to Wikipedia or interact on discussion pages, then those TOU apply. But if the app is just reusing the content of Wikipedia, what the footer says (generally,CC-BY-SA) is pretty much all that matters.